# Accessing the number of processors in WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

I have looked through a number of posts on here regarding the WMI and am still having a little trouble. I would like to retrive the CPU useage from WMI, my query retrieves everything the ManagementObjectSearcher has to offer, but it returns a null and never pulls any information back.

Also, for the datatype I am pulling should I be using a int16?

Hopefully someone can shed a little light on this and send me on my way. Thanks.

```
public void GetPhysicalMemory()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher mgtObj = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");   // Win32_OPeratingSystem");
    ManagementObjectCollection mgtColl = mgtObj.Get();

   // foreach (ManagementObject obj in  mgtObj.Get())
    if (mgtColl.Count != 0 )
    {
        foreach (ManagementBaseObject mgtBaseObj in mgtColl)
        {
            var[] data = mgtBaseObj["NumberOfProcessors"] as int16[];

            if (data != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(data);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Collection = null");
                Console.Read();
                Console.Read();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want get the number of processors or the CPU usage?

Comment: I am actually looking more to return the CPU usage, I was taking stabs in the dark to pull back anything with NumberOfProcessors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can can iterate directly over the collection returned by [ManagementObjectSearcher.Get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67a77ef1.aspx)  method using a [ManagementObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject.aspx) variable,   from here you can access you can access each property using the item property or  through the [] notation.

Check this sample application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleFoo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher mgtObj = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
                foreach (ManagementObject item in mgtObj.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Number Of Processors  {0}", item["NumberOfProcessors"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception {0} ", e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know which collection carries the cpu usage?

Comment: you must access the performance counters, try using classes like [Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)